# Best practice for > < and == in a function

Tags: php, if-statement, integer, comparison

I have come across a conundrum which I usually just use a bunch of ifs or a switch.

To put this in perspective, the current project I am working on involves comparing the width and height of an image to get a number to determine if the width is longer than the height or the same.

Here is my code so far:

```
private function compare($width, $height)
{
    return $width - $height;
}
```

This works as you might expect.

What I would like to find out is if there is a better way to do this:

```
    if($this->compare($this->width, $this->height) == 0)
    {

    }
    if($this->compare($this->width, $this->height) < 0)
    {

    }
    if($this->compare($this->width, $this->height) > 0)
    {

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: why bother having the 3rd test? there's only 3 possibilities, so just use an `else. `if ( equal ) else if (greater) else (...)`. once you've eliminated the first two posiiblities, it has to be the else, which is less-than.

Comment: Wouldn't the normal thing to do here be using `if else else if`, as in, `if ($this->width > $this->height)` etc? No need for the `compare` function.

Comment: if i was having a function, i would like to know, 'portrait', landscape' or 'square'. It will read better in the code imo. just me.

Comment: PHP7 is going to add to your options, and give you even more choices with the spaceship (`<=>`) operator

Comment: On occasion I find that something has been introduced to make things like this easier (like the upcoming comment from @MarkBaker). As there is currently no better solution I will find a method using ifs and probably elses although I hate using them.

Comment: @bbill Yes normally I would probably stick it all in one but for the purposes of the question, I wanted to remove it from the answer as it doesnt matter what data the comparison function is using or how it creates the data and it keeps it simple.

Answer (score 2):

For the value returned by the method compare(), you have only three posibilities, so we just have to do two conditions and can obmit one:

```
$recievedValue = $this->compare($this->width, $this->height);
if( $recievedValue == 0 )
{
     // The value is equal to 0
}
else if( $recievedValue < 0 )
{
    // The value is less than 0
}
else
{
    // The value is more than 0
}
```

Comment: Hola. Este sito es en inglés, y desgraciadamente no se aceptan respuestas en otros idiomas. Editaré tu respuesta a inglés, pero para el futuro, deberías publicar en inglés

Comment: I know, however SO *is* branching out into other languages: there is a [Portugese site](http://pt.stackoverflow.com) and a [Russian site](http://ru.stackoverflow.com). Fingers crossed there will be a Spanish one soon

Comment: Great, but i'm from Colombia and i only speak spanish, i'll answer in english next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it psr2 complainant:

```
if ($this->compare($this->width, $this->height) == 0) {

} elseif ($this->compare($this->width, $this->height) < 0) {

} else {

}
```

Read more:
[PSR-2 Coding Style Guide](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md)

Comment: Thanks, your suggested method looks similar in style to the 3 ifs option but I really don't like the PSR-2 styling of if brackets. Its a personal project so will stick to keeping it opened.